# Not able to understand Atoi function - *string - '0'

Tags: c, string, atoi

What exactly does the below statement do?

```
const char *string
*string - '0'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It subtracts the value of the character `'0'` from the character pointed to by `string`, turning it into a numerical value. So for example the character `'9'` will be turned into the integer `9`.